# Firefox minimizes when using "Always on Visible Workspace" on an hdmi dual monitor

Tags: unity, firefox, multiple-monitors, compiz, workspaces

I've never used the always on visible workspace feature without the dual monitor setup, so it's not clear to me whether that part is related.

When I pin a firefox window to every workspace on one monitor and then use other applications on the other monitor, then click back on the pinned firefox window, it has a nasty tendency to minimize. Since that isn't the only firefox window I have open, I can't get it to return by simply clicking on the firefox icon on my system tray - I have to close every other firefox window and then click on the icon. Even then it initially goes to whatever application I had been working on before I clicked on the firefox window.

I have no idea what could be causing this bizarre behavior, and my efforts to google haven't really turned up anything helpful unfortunately.

My Ubuntu version 16.04:

```
dustan@dustan-Aspire-E5-575:~$ uname -a
Linux dustan-Aspire-E5-575 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running Mozilla Firefox 55.0.2. Please let me know what other details might be helpful.

Window manager information:

```
dustan@dustan-Aspire-E5-575:~$ wmctrl -m
Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
dustan@dustan-Aspire-E5-575:~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
ubuntu
dustan@dustan-Aspire-E5-575:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
Unity
```

Comment: What's your window manager / desktop compositor? FWIW I can't reproduce this issue with Gnome Shell v3.10.4.

Comment: @DavidFoerster edited. I'm not sure how to get version information though.